# Reflection method invoke object does not match target type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It's working, but is not dynamic for `as CustomRepository<ApplicationUser>`:

```
public class CheckUnique : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        Type genericClass = typeof(CustomRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(ApplicationUser));

        var xx = validationContext.GetService(genericClass) as CustomRepository<ApplicationUser>;

        var res = xx.IsValid(value, "username");
        if (!res)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("exist", new[] { "name" });
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like change this`as CustomRepository<ApplicationUser>` to some using reflection or other way. If not I should use many different validation for check unique value..

When I try use:

```
        MethodInfo method = genericClass.GetMethod("IsValid");
        object params = new object [] { value, "username" };
        object val = method.Invoke(this, params );
```

I get error -  object does not match target type and don't undestand why.

Some from **CustomRepository.cs**

```
public class CustomRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    public CustomRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public bool IsValid(object value, string prop)
    {
      business logic...
    }
}
```

On **Startup.cs**

```
  services.AddScoped(typeof(CustomRepository<>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument should be an instance of the type that the MethodInfo belongs to-- a `CustomRepository<ApplicationUser>`. You are passing a `CheckUnique`.

So instead of

```
object val = method.Invoke(this, params );
```

try

```
object val = method.Invoke(xx, params );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [John Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2791540/john-wu)

I have changed to:

```
            Type genericClass = typeof(CustomRepository<>).MakeGenericType(_typeObject);
            var invokeObject = validationContext.GetService(genericClass);

            var parameters = new object [] { value, "username" };
            MethodInfo method = genericClass.GetMethod("IsValid");
            object getCheck = method.Invoke(invokeObject, parameters);
```